# Why career profile page looks broken?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs

I just tried a few minutes ago my [career](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/SonerGonul) page, the page looks like broken. This is how it looks like in Firefox 19.0.2

[image]

Here how it is looks like in Chrome 25.0.1364.152

[image]

I tried with also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> a few times but nothing happened.

Comment: But you look pretty good still, so it's not *thaaat* bad :p

Comment: in 18.0.2 it's fine tho.. Hmm? you're seeing this part? <img alt="Stack Overflow" class="favicon" src="http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico">

Comment: What a clever plot to get visits to your Careers page ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could not reproduce in current Safari, Chrome, or Firefox. I suspect this was just a deploy bug where we changed some CSS and the website and CDN were out of sync for a minute or so.